# Regex to say not this character in MongoDB

Tags: regex, mongodb

I'm doing some work with mongodb and Regex.

So, I have run:

```
{
   "email": /@/
}
```

Now I want to say:

```
{
   "email": does not contain @
}
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Change the regex to `/[^@]/` which is a negative character class or you can use `$ne` there

Comment: @Sammaye - that's incorrect. That will simply verify that a non-'@' symbol appears in the input. It will not signal that no '@' appears in the input.

Comment: @Sammaye That RE will match any string that is not a sequence of "@" or an empty string. It should be `/^[^@]*$/`.

Comment: Meh I wrote it quickly...hence why I didnt post an answer

Comment: @pingw33n - that looks like the correct answer to me. Perhaps you should actually post it.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks guys

{
"email":/^[^@]*$/
}

Worked perfect

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- Use `{email: /^[^@]*$/}`.
- Or use `{email: {$not: /@/}}`.